# R dummies package weird column names when knitted via .Rmd

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

I've just noticed a very weird behavior in the `dummies` package of R when knitted in `.Rmd`. Here's the reproducible example.

````
---
title: "Dummies Package Behavior"
author: "Kim"
date: '`r Sys.Date()`'
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '3'
---

Load the libraries

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(dummies)
```

Main data wrangling

```{r}
df <- data_frame(year = c(2016, 2017, 2018))
temp <- dummy(df$year)
temp <- as_data_frame(temp)
df <- bind_cols(df, temp)
```

View output

```{r}
df
```
````

What I'm expecting to see when I view the `df` are nice 0-1 columns of `year2016`, `year2017`, and `year2018`, which is the normal behavior for the `dummies` package.

When you knit this R Markdown document in RStudio, it instead brings out the following: `C:/Users/Kim/Desktop/dummies.Rmd2016`,  `C:/Users/Kim/Desktop/dummies.Rmd2017`, and  `C:/Users/Kim/Desktop/dummies.Rmd2018`. That is, it uses the whole document address to make the column names.

I don't understand why such behavior occurs. Obviously, I want to have column names as `year2016`, `year2017`, and `year2018`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to `dplyr` because we can reproduce it with `data.frame()`. Apparently there is a problem with assigning column labels in the `dummy()` function when executed as part of an R Markdown document.  As noted in Luke's answer, one workaround is to use `dummy.data.frame()`.  Another would be to use the `colnames()` function to rename the columns after binding the year and dummy variables with `cbind()`, which also enables a `dplyr`-based solution.

This should probably be submitted as a bug report for the `dummies` package.

````
---
title: "Behavior of dummies package"
author: "anAuthor"
date: "12/26/2017"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# first, reproduce error with data.frame()

```{r}
library(dummies)
df <- data.frame(year = c(2016, 2017, 2018))
df
dummyCols <- dummy(df$year)
dummyCols <- as.data.frame(dummyCols)
dummyCols
```

# data.frame() approach to fix the error

```{r}
df <- data.frame(year = c(2016, 2017, 2018))
df
dummyCols <- dummy.data.frame(data=df,dummy.classes="ALL")
dummyCols
df <- cbind(df, dummyCols)
df
```
````

...and the output, first reproducing the error.

[image]

...second, using `dummies.data.frame()` to avoid the error.

[image]

The `dplyr` correction works as follows.

````
# dplyr approach 

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(year = c(2016, 2017, 2018))
temp <- dummy(df$year)
temp <- as_data_frame(temp)
df <- bind_cols(df, temp)
colnames(df) <- c("year",unlist(lapply(2016:2018,function(x) {
     paste("year",x,sep="")
})))
df
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you Len. I will be indeed filing a bug report for the ```dummies``` package.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that interaction is happening, but this slight modification seems to get around it:

````
```{r}
df <- data.frame(year = c(2016, 2017, 2018))
df <- data.frame(df, dummy.data.frame(data = df, dummy.classes = "ALL"))
```
````

[image]

Note that `data.frame` from base rather than `data_frame` from `dplyr` seems to make a difference.